# Feed Parsing In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, routes, hyperlink, feed

I am working on Ubuntu 10.04 and I am using feed-zirra to parse RSS feeds and I have MySQL database.

I am trying to parse RSS feeds from [Times of India Top Stories](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms). There seems to be problem with the first link, I am sure TOI guys will correct it soon. But anyway, I dont want to face similar error later so thats why I want to ask you guys how to solve this problem.

Just look at this and ***especially look for link***

```
<item>
  <title>CWG: Abhinav Bindra, Gagan Narang win first Gold for India</title
  <description>Abhinav Bindra and Gagan Narang on Tuesday bagged Gold for the men's 10 m air rifle pair's event, getting India its first gold in the 19th Commonwealth Games.</description>
<link>/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms</link>
<guid>/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 05 Oct 2010 04:57:46 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

The link is `<link>/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms</link>`

Now, when I click the link, in the view.. its getting routed to http://localhost:3000/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms instead of http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms

And the error I am getting is

```
**Routing Error**

No route matches "/cwgarticleshow/6688747.cms" with {:method=>:get}
```

How do I correct this type of Error?

Looking forward for your help and support

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prepend `http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com` to the link tag value and you'll be ok.

Comment: I am a newbie. Could you tell me how can this be achieved? I didnt understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URI class. You can, for example, define following method

```
require "uri"

def repair_link(feed_link)
  uri = URI.parse(feed_link)
  uri.scheme ||= "http"
  uri.host   ||= "timesofindia.indiatimes.com"
  uri.to_s
end
```

It will set the scheme and host part of the URL if they are not already filled. So if you call it for normal link (like `http://foo/bar.cms`) then nothing will be changed.

And last thing - you probably should catch exception somewhere as the #parse method raises exception InvalidURIError in case of invalid URI. But it's up to you how you will deal with it.